# Using a Ukelele-created keyboard doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard, ukelele

I tired to do the following:

1. Select the original US Keyboard layout as my current keyboard.
2. Launched Ukelele
3. Chose New > From current input source
4. Swapped a single key
5. Saved the file in my keyboard layouts and chose it as my input method.

Now when I try to type in Chrome, it doesn't output anything. It works fine in other apps such as TextEdit, though.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try rebooting.

This helped me to globally apply a new keyboard layout - often logging out and back in helps, sometimes you need a reboot.

Comment: Merely restarting *Chrome* did the trick for me.